# How to get current user name as related field odoo

Tags: python, odoo-13

```html
<record id="product.product_normal_action_sell" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Product Variants</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">product.product</field>
            <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form,activity</field>
            <field name="context">{"search_default_filter_to_sell":1}</field>
            <field name="domain">[('user', '=', "Ignored value")]</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="product.product_product_tree_view"/>
            <field name="search_view_id" ref="product.product_search_form_view"/>
            <field name="help" type="html">
              <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
                Create a new product variant
              </p><p>
                You must define a product for everything you sell, whether it's a physical product,
                a consumable or a service you offer to customers.
                The product form contains information to simplify the sale process:
                price, notes in the quotation, accounting data, procurement methods, etc.
              </p>
            </field>
        </record>
```

I want to always change user field when login.
I know i can use the default but default function will not effect the exiting product.I want to user related field for this.Pls suggest me.

```
_inherit = 'product.template'
_description = "Product filter"
category_branch = fields.Many2one('multi.branch', string="Branch Name",related="categ_id.branch_id",rea
```

```html
class ResUsers(models.Model):
    """Res Users Model."""

    _inherit = 'res.users'

    @api.model
    def _get_branch(self):
        return self.env.user.branch_id
    branch_id = fields.Many2one('multi.branch', string='Branch',
                                default=_get_branch,
                                help='The branch this user is currently \
                                working for.')
```

donly=True)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Related fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#related-fields) are a special case of computed fields that are related (proxy) fields, which provide the value of a sub-field on the current record.

The value of a related field is given by following a sequence of relational fields and reading a field on the reached model. The complete sequence of fields to traverse is specified by the `related` attribute.

`self.env.user` is not a sequence of relational fields, you can't use it in `related` parameter.

You need to define it as a computed field to get the value of the current user and return it when requested.

```py
def _get_current_user(self):
    for r in self:
        r.user_id = self.env.user

def _search_branch(self, operator, value):
        return [('categ_id.branch_id', operator, self.env.user.branch_id.id)]

user = fields.Many2one('res.users', compute='_get_current_user', search='_search_branch')
```

***Edit:***
searching on a computed field can be enabled by setting the search parameter. The value is a method name returning a [Search domains](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#reference-orm-domains).

The search method is invoked when processing domains before doing an actual search on the model. It must return a domain equivalent to the condition: `field operator value`.

You need to replace the `value` parameter returned by the search domain to `self.env.user.branch_id.id` then try to use the following domain in the product template action:

```
[('user', '=', "Ignored value")]
```

***Example:***

```py
class ResUsers(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.users'

    branch_id = fields.Many2one('multi.branch')


class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.category'

    branch_id = fields.Many2one('multi.branch')


class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    user = fields.Many2one("res.users", compute='_get_current_user', search='_search_branch')

    def _get_current_user(self):
        for r in self:
            r.user_branch = self.env.user.id

    def _search_branch(self, operator, value):
        return [('categ_id.branch_id', operator, self.env.user.branch_id.id)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But compute field cant user for domain filter, I want to use this field as domain filter.When i add store=True ,the exiting product is empty for this field.Can you help me how can i do that?My problem is every user login change this user field in product and want filter for current login user.

Comment: It is not clear, please explain what you need to achieve and how you need to filter it.

Comment: Actually I want to add one field like user for each product and when login current user is the same with user in product , I only want display product that same user in product view of sale.Not display the product that are not same with current user.

Comment: When i filter with user in product view of sale , only show product that user field is same with current login user.

Comment: Do you need to assign a product to a specific user?

Comment: Sure.That mean the user own this product and i want to show only his product

Comment: You need to remove the compute attribute and use the following domain: `domain="[('user_id', '=', uid)]"`, `uid` is the current user `id`.If you need to set the ``user`` when you create a product to the current user use a default value. If you add a computed field which set its value to the current user then use a domain to look for product that have user equal to the current user, it will be always true for all users.

Comment: Actually i have branch_id that is many2one field in product and its also have in current user .So, I have to use domain filter like domain=[('branch_id','=',user.branch_id)] .I don't need user id .But i cant use user in xml file.

Comment: Use `uid` on the right side to compare to the current user id.

Comment: Pls check my code.I edited. I have category_branch in product and also has in current login user.So i if they are same , I want to display that product in product view.If not he can't see this product

Comment: If you want to filter products using the `category_branch`, just compare to `uid`. You do not need to use `self.env.user`.

Comment: No user field in product template field.Only have category_branch field.So i want to user like domain=[('branch_id','=',user.branch_id)]. It doesn't work.

Comment: I know my question is not clear.Now I added my code fully.Pls check. I have category brand in product.template and branch_id in res.users. I want to make if the current user login branch_id is same with product's category_branch, I want to display in product view of sale

Comment: @AungKoKoLin Try to enable searching on user field, Check my edit.

Comment: I still see all product for each login .And I don't understand [('user', '=', "Ignored value")] means what?

Comment: The value passed in the domain is ignored `[(field, operator, value)]`. Did you define the field like in the example above?

Comment: I defined field like you write.I add my xml action code.Pls check

Comment: Try to update a product variant and set the category branch to the current user branch.

Comment: No.It doesn't work. Can you help me to write code fully?

Comment: Use my example above then go under ``Purchases/Products`` and select ``Product Variants`` then edit the action to add the domain manually.

Comment: Really sorry @kenly . It's work. I wrong inherit product action.Now It's work.Thank you so much.

Comment: I have another problem @kenly. I want to display only login warehouse products which warehouse quantity is greater than 0 in sale order line.Can you help me?

Comment: It seems like a new question, please ask a new question and I will check it if I have time

Comment: Thank you @kenly. If you have time , please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63647263/product-filter-with-stock-quantity-in-sale-order-line-in-odoo.

Comment: If you have time , pls check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63773843/filter-journal-item-in-general-ledger-report-in-accounting-odoo