# Filter Journal Item in General Ledger report in accounting odoo

Tags: python-3.x, report, odoo-13

All bank account and their journal items are shown in general ledger. I have branch_id field in journal item and current login user also has branch_id field. I want to only display journal item that their branch_id is same with current's user branch_id. How can I filter journal item and recalculate their debit and credit and balance in general ledger report?

```html
@api.model
    def _get_report_line_move_line(self, options, partner, aml, cumulated_init_balance, cumulated_balance):
        if aml['payment_id']:
            caret_type = 'account.payment'
        elif aml['move_type'] in ('in_refund', 'in_invoice', 'in_receipt'):
            caret_type = 'account.invoice.in'
        elif aml['move_type'] in ('out_refund', 'out_invoice', 'out_receipt'):
            caret_type = 'account.invoice.out'
        else:
            caret_type = 'account.move'

        date_maturity = aml['date_maturity'] and format_date(self.env, fields.Date.from_string(aml['date_maturity']))
        columns = [
            {'name': aml['journal_code']},
            {'name': aml['account_code']},
            {'name': self._format_aml_name(aml['name'], aml['ref'], aml['move_name'])},
            {'name': date_maturity or '', 'class': 'date'},
            {'name': aml['full_rec_name'] or ''},
            {'name': self.format_value(cumulated_init_balance), 'class': 'number'},
            {'name': self.format_value(aml['debit'], blank_if_zero=True), 'class': 'number'},
            {'name': self.format_value(aml['credit'], blank_if_zero=True), 'class': 'number'},
        ]
        if self.user_has_groups('base.group_multi_currency'):
            if aml['currency_id']:
                currency = self.env['res.currency'].browse(aml['currency_id'])
                formatted_amount = self.format_value(aml['amount_currency'], currency=currency, blank_if_zero=True)
                columns.append({'name': formatted_amount, 'class': 'number'})
            else:
                columns.append({'name': ''})
        columns.append({'name': self.format_value(cumulated_balance), 'class': 'number'})
        return {
            'id': aml['id'],
            'parent_id': 'partner_%s' % partner.id,
            'name': format_date(self.env, aml['date']),
            'class': 'date',
            'columns': columns,
            'caret_options': caret_type,
            'level': 4,
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to alter the [General Ledger](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/account/views/account_move_views.xml#L1207) action domain.

You can define a server action that gets the original action definition and alter the domain before returning the result then associate it with the `General Ledger` menu item under `Accounting/Ledgers`.

***Example:***

```
<record model="ir.actions.server" id="action_account_moves_ledger_general">
        <field name="name">General Ledger</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="account.model_account_move_line"/>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code">
action = env.ref('account.action_account_moves_ledger_general').read()[0]
action['domain'] = "[('display_type', 'not in', ('line_section', 'line_note')), ('branch_id', '=', {})]".format( env.user.branch_id.id)
        </field>
</record>

<record model="ir.ui.menu" id="account.menu_action_account_moves_ledger_general">
    <field name="action" ref="action_account_moves_ledger_general"/>
</record>
```

Comment: When I check general ledger code, they write with ir.actions.client.They are client action.Can I use server action?

Comment: I mention about general ledger under accounting reporting menu.

Comment: I added some code.Pls check this.It is odoo13 enterprise.Thanks

Comment: Try to override ``_get_options_domain`` or pass the domain from client side using options.

Comment: @Kenly.Override change something but still wrong because when i click account and click journal entry of some invoice or payment, branch is not the same with current user branch.

Comment: Did you try to pass the domain from the client side?

Comment: I dont know how to pass domain from client side?Can you tell me?@Kenly

Comment: For example in account [reconciliation](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/account/static/src/js/reconciliation/reconciliation_model.js#L409), you can override `self.domain`) which is passed as a search domain or override the [get_bank_statement_data](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/account/models/reconciliation_widget.py#L217). Try to do something similar with `account_report` tag.

Comment: @Kenly.Please check my code I edited. I have four model and pass to caret_type.All model has branch_id and I think if current user branch is same with model's branch id return that .If not same, not return.Can you help me how can I add domain?@Kenly

Comment: It seems that the method is used to return one account move line data, in your case if the branch is not the same, you need to ignore the line, try to check the code using `_get_report_line_move_line` method.

Comment: No.It's return account move or account payment .They have branch_id in each.So I don't want to return it's branch_id is not the same with current user's branch_id.How can I do that?@Kenly

Comment: Try to add the condition when Odoo calls the method if it is evaluated to False ignore the call.

Comment: @KenlyNo.It's return account move or account payment .They have branch_id in each.So I don't want to return it's branch_id is not the same with current user's branch_id.How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell, I can't test it and I do not know how it is implemented. What I told you in my previous comment is to check for brach id and if it is different do not call the method and add the line to the result.